# Is it possible to access to the files from a hard disk connected as external?

Tags: hard-drive

Is it possible to access to the files from a hard disk connected as external? I mean, without logging in.

Im scared about someone at work to take out the hard disk from my computer, then make a copy, and see the files inside my hard-disk.

Comment: So you have external HDD pluged in (USB I guess), then you lock your computer....yes, if they unplug it, I don't see problem why they couldn't. But if you encrypt that HDD...different story

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

If you have physical access, then you own the computer. Full encryption is the only option to prevent that - and that includes denying you access if the key goes missing.

Otherwise, you just mount the drive (or it's image) in a PC where you are root...

Answer (score 0):

Having physical access to an unencrypted hard drive definitely allows an attacker to gain access to your files. So the best way to protect your data is to use full disk encryption. If your hard drive support drive locking , you can enable that. You can read a little bit about it here: https://security.stackexchange.com/a/33419

There's also another way to steal the data,even without removing the hard drive. Booting LiveCD and `chroot`ing the system, allows the attacker to manipulate your data even without removing it from the machine - just takes physical access to it.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question at all.  He is asking if you can pull the drive out of the system, plug it into another, and access the files on it.

Comment: Ah, I thought OP's asked if it's possible to copy his files over if an external drive is connected. I'll edit my answer

Comment: Edited. Please review